# Getting error while trying to map over array. TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So for the practice I am trying to consume rest point with react framework. 
But somehow I getting error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Json look like this:

```
{  
   "name":"sadasd.tx",
   "application":"Word",
   "id":"123",
   "type":"Mixed",
   "containers":[  
      "Variant1",
      "Variant2_sch",
      "Variant5",
      "Variant6",
      "Variant3",
      "Variant4"
   ]
}
```

React component looks like this:

```
class ContainerList extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={fileContent: []};
    }

    componentDidMount(){   
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/'+ this.props.file)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                        this.setState({fileContent: data})
        })
    }

    render() {
        const containerNames = this.state.fileContent.containers.map(container => <Container containerName={container} />);

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {containerNames}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

After removing map over array and debugging in browser I see that json object is correctly assigned to the variable. But when iterating over it I getting undefined error. Anyone has idea what might be wrong?

[EDIT]
I am completely does not understand this. I did understand why does it throwing this error, after your posts guys. But I did something like this after reading your answers:

I added to `state` another variable `isLoading` with default true value. And in fetch after getting json I set it to false.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/'+ this.props.xx)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
                    this.setState({fileContent: data, isLoading: false})
    })
```

and in render method I did add if statement:

```
render() {
        let containerNames;

        if(this.state.isLoading){
            containerNames = <h1>Loading</h1>

        }else{
            containerNames = this.state.fileContent.listContainers.map(listContainer => <Container listContainerName={listContainer} />);
        }

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>

                    {containerNames}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
```

So it should not be possible to enter else statemend before fetchind data. But react is somehow doing this. And throwing error.

Comment: If `render()` is called before the `fetch()` completes, that `fileContent` object will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During initial render value of `this.state.fileContent.containers` will be undefined, and `undefined` do not have `map` method

You add check before `map`

```
const containerNames = Array.isArray(this.state.fileContent.containers) && this.state.fileContent.containers.map(
```

Comment: You are right, I did add this check. It helps with the error,. But component does not rerender after data is loaded

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { fileContent } = this.state
const { containers } = fileContent
const containerName = containers ? containers : []
```

like the other answers mentioned, containers doesn't exist during the initial render. here i did some desconstructing for personal preferences, but i'm just stating if containers exist, then map over it, otherwise map over an empty array